# "Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes"

Tags: mysql, indexing

I can't create index on `varchar(500)`.

MySQL: `Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes`

Comment: The complete answer to this question is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes/1814594#1814594).

Comment: Here is 1 line short and completely working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes/22873006#22873006

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
latin1 = 1 byte = 1 character
uft8 = 3 byte = 1 character
gbk = 2 byte = 1 character
```

Comment: Shouldn't utf-8 characters be of variable length (1-4), depending on the unicode code point?

Comment: The maximum number of bytes needed for one utf8 character is 3, and MySQL must make provision for all of the characters in te field to be the maximum number of bytes.

Comment: Except the maximum number of bytes on UTF-8 is 4 bytes.  MySQL made this stupid, stupid, stupid, horribly evil decision to make utf8 only support 3 bytes.  The "real" UTF-8 compatible charset is utf8mb4, only supported on MySQL 5.6.